# Finding and counting if there are the correct number of vowels in a sentence

Tags: java, string

I've been looking around the site and can't find an answer to my question. I need to be able to look through a given amount of strings and count the amount of vowels in the word. If the amount of vowels match the numbers entered before, then print YES. If one word doesn't have the right amount of vowels, print NO. I tried using a String array then going through each word in the array to look for the vowels, increment the vowel check (vocheck) for every vowel it finds, then check if vocheck equals the appropriate number. But, when I check to see if the vocheck for loop works, it just keeps vocheck as 0. What's wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
public class verses {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int lines = input.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[lines];
        int vowels = 0;
        boolean vcheck = true;
        int vocheck = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
            arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        }   
        String[] word = new String[lines];
        for(int x = 0; x < word.length; x++){
            word[x] = input.nextLine();
        }
        word[word.length-1] = input.nextLine();

        for(int m = 0; m < lines; m++){
            for(int y = 0; y < word[y].length(); y++){
                if(word[m].charAt(y) == 'a'
                        || word[m].equals('e')
                        || word[m].equals('i')
                        || word[m].equals('o')
                        || word[m].equals('u')
                        || word[m].equals('y')){
                    vocheck++;
                }
            }
            if(vocheck != arr[m]){
                vcheck = false;
            }
        }

        if(vcheck == true){
            System.out.println("YES");
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO");
        }

    }



}
```

This is what a sample input would look like
3
2 2 3
intel
code
challenge

This should print YES because there are three words, the first has 2 vowels, the second has 2 vowels, and the third has 3 vowels

Comment: Always show sample input and expected output. Because there could be better solutions to your problem and without sample input / output, we can do nothing

Comment: Why do you have a space between "ch" and "allenge"?

Comment: It's how the sample input is. I guess so the code checks an entire line? It still treats it like a single word though

Comment: Ok I realized that in the y for loop, I needed to change word[y].length() to word[m].length(). But, when I System.out.println(vocheck) right before it checks for vcheck = false, it keeps vocheck 0 the first time around.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take advantage of some [basic debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and let us know if you have a more specific question we can answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

- Add `input.nextLine();` before reading words. This is necessary otherwise first entry in array `word` would be rest of the part of the previous line.
- `word[word.length-1] = input.nextLine();` is not necessary
- `vocheck` must be initialized for each iteration of the loop
- `for(int y = 0; y < word[y].length(); y++){` should be `for(int y = 0; y < word[m].length(); y++){`. Notice `y` is changed to `m`.
- Also other conditions are not consistent. They shouldn't be like `word[m].equals('e')` but like `word[m].charAt(y) == 'e'`

  ```
  import java.util.*;public class verses {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int lines = input.nextInt();
      int[] arr = new int[lines];
      int vowels = 0;
      boolean vcheck = true;
      int vocheck = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
          arr[i] = input.nextInt();
      }
      input.nextLine();
      String[] word = new String[lines];
      for(int x = 0; x < word.length; x++){
          word[x] = input.nextLine();
      }
      //word[word.length-1] = input.nextLine();

      for(int m = 0; m < lines; m++){
          vocheck = 0;
          for(int y = 0; y < word[m].length(); y++){
              if(word[m].charAt(y) == 'a'
                      || word[m].charAt(y) == 'e'
                      || word[m].charAt(y) == 'i'
                      || word[m].charAt(y) == 'o'
                      || word[m].charAt(y) == 'u'
                      || word[m].charAt(y) == 'y'){
                  vocheck++;
              }
          }
          if(vocheck != arr[m]){
              vcheck = false;
          }

      }
      if(vcheck == true){
          System.out.println("YES");
      }else{
          System.out.println("NO");
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Here what? Hint : you better provide some explanations.

Comment: That works for the first two words, but for the ch allenge, it sees it as false when it needs to be true. It also prints the YES or NO every time it checks the word, when it just needs to print once

Comment: I did all of these, but when I put in the sample input, it gives me YES YES NO, but the last one, ch allenge, should be YES, because it needs to check the whole line.

Comment: ok. got it. I understood it differently. Will post changes soon.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these word[m].equals('e') and use like you used first time
word[m].charAt(y) == 'a'.

And 
for(int y = 0; y < word[y].length(); y++) //use word[m]

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {2, 3, 2};
    boolean vcheck = true;

    String[] word = {"ch ale", "fa jio", "gt eyu"};//new String[lines];

    int vocheck = 0;
    for(int m = 0; m < 3; m++){
        vocheck = 0;
        for(int y = 0; y < word[m].length(); y++){          
            if(word[m].charAt(y) == 'a'
                    || word[m].charAt(y) == 'e'
                    || word[m].charAt(y) == 'i'
                    || word[m].charAt(y) == 'o'
                    || word[m].charAt(y) == 'u')
            {
                vocheck++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(vocheck);
        if(vocheck != arr[m]){
            vcheck = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(vcheck == true){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }else{
        System.out.println("NO");
    }

}
```

}

Try it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
    if(word[i].toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^aeiouy]", "").length() == arr[i]){
        System.out.println("Word " + word[i] + " has " + arr[i] + " vowels");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Word " + word[i] + " DOESN'T HAVE " + arr[i] + " vowels");
    }
}
```

What this `word[i].toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^aeiouy]", "").length()` does is to change all letters in the word to lowercase (`toLowerCase()`), replace all non-vowels characters from it (`replaceAll("[^aeiouy]", "")`) and get the number of remaining characters (`length()`), the number of vowels.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try some regex :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String s = "4 2 2 3 2 intel code challenge aa";
    s = s.replaceAll("(?i)[^\\daeiou ]", ""); // replace all consonants with empty String.
    String[] arr = s.split("\\s+"); // Split based on space.
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    for (int i = 1; i <= arr.length / 2; i++) {
    // Check for equality of String lengths and input values
        if (Integer.parseInt(arr[i]) == arr[arr.length / 2 + i].length()) {
            count++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO");
            return;
        }
    }
    // Check if counts of String are same as number of Strings
    if (count != Integer.parseInt(arr[0])) {
        System.out.println("NO");
    } else {
        System.out.println("YES");
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
[4, 2, 2, 3, 2, ie, oe, aee, aa]
YES
```

Comment: "Why don't you try some regex?" Because regex are very slow so it should always be your last resort

Comment: @NicolasFilotto - Regexes aren't always slow. 2. They aren't always used a s the last resort :)

Comment: How do I convert this to inputs rather than set String values? This works but I have multiple sample inputs it needs to check for

Comment: @AndrewSanders - Use `scanner.nextLine()` to read an entire line of input (consisting of total count, individual vowel count as well as the words) and assign it to `s`. Use a loop in case you read multiple sets of such things

Comment: Alright, I used 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int lines = input.nextInt();
  for(int m = 0; m < lines; m++){
     String s = input.nextLine();

but then it throws a NumberFormatException error with the Integer.parseInt line

Comment: @AndrewSanders - add just a `input.nextLine();` after  `int lines = input.nextInt();` :)

Comment: It still gives me the wrong answer :/ For the first test case it says no, though it should be yes

Comment: @AndrewSanders - Works for me. Gives Yes. Are you sure that there aren't any additional whitespaces there?.  What do you see when you debug?

Comment: Wait it just worked for me too there! Thanks so much!!
Also, Balkrishna Rawool solved it as well!

Comment: OK let's be more specific for example a regular expression can hardly be short-circuited which is not the case of a simple for loop and when we use a regular expression we need to be aware of how it works internally because for example here you should not use `String#replaceAll` and `String#split` directly because it will compile the regex at each call which is terrible in term of performances, I guess you already know that but the OP probably doesn't. Please don't take it as an offense but just as a note